# Move points in the opposite direction

Tags: java, geometry

I am working on a project in Java. I am trying to move the points `p2`, `p3`, `p4` just outside the circumference of the circle in the opposite direction to the point p1. Below is the image, which describes the problem, I am trying to solve.

[image: Moving Points to the edge of the circle]

```
//given two points, calculates the angle
public static double calcAngle(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
    double deltaX = p2.x - p1.x;
    double deltaY = p2.y - p1.y;
    return (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI);
}

//calculates a point on a circle given the angle, center of the circle and the radius
public static Point2D.Double pointOnCircle(Point2D.Double point, double radius , double angle) {
    double x = Math.abs(point.x + (radius * Math.cos(angle  * Math.PI / 180F)));
    double y = Math.abs(point.y + (radius * Math.sin(angle  * Math.PI / 180F)));
    return new Point2D.Double(x,y);
}
```

How do I calculate the angle in Java coordinate system and destination co-ordinates for each of the points `p2`, `p3`, `p4`?

I am yet to try the code above and would like to know if my approach is right before proceeding, since it is a part of the bigger project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without more details, I'd say you're moving in the right direction

Comment: Although the above works, I'd say it is needlessly laborious to use angles and trigonometry; just use vector math instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general idea seems workable but overly complicated. There is no need to convert from x/y-vector to angle and then back. SImply scaling vectors will be enough.

```
Point2D p = p2; // likewise for p3, p4
double factor = radius / p.distance(p1);
p.setLocation(p1.getX() + (p.getX() - p1.getX())*factor,
              p1.getY() + (p.getY() - p1.getY())*factor);
```

This takes the vector `(p - p1)`, i.e. the vector pointing from `p1` towards `p`, scales it by `factor` and adds it to the position of `p1`. The `factor` is chosen such that the new distance is equal to `radius`.

All of this will fail if `p1` and `p` are the same, since in this case you'll have a division by zero. If this can be a problem for you, you might want to ensure that `factor` is a finite number, e.g. using [`Double.isFinite(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isFinite-double-).